# DataSet to Excel through OleDB

Tags: vb.net, excel, oledb

I'm using OleDB to access my Excel "database". It's all working wonderfully. I have four sheets in my Excel file, and they technically have their own primary keys and such. In my program, I copy those four sheets into four tables in a DataSet through OleDB, and then use LinQ to join the tables and put them into one table, which I use to show stuff to the user. The user modifies information, then presses save. The DataSet is updated, and then I try to push the changes through OleDB to Excel. Unfortunately I get errors at this point telling me I don't have key column information.

I understand that I haven't set anything to specifically say which columns are used as primary keys in my Excel file. When I copy the sheets to my DataSet, I do set the primary keys there.

THE POINT:  Is there a way to set primary keys for excel columns? Even if it's at runtime, that's okay. Just as good is if there's a way for me to tell OleDB to use the primary keys set on my DataSet. All I want is to be able to use Commandbuilder.

EDIT: Here's the code where I'm doing the update. (I don't know why pressing the Code Sample button isn't lining it up properly)

```
  Using MyConnection As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connectionString)




  For Each query In bidSummaryQueries
                Try
                    MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(query(1), MyConnection)
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MsgBox(query(0) & " connection failed." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & ex.Message)
                End Try
                Dim MyBuilder As OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder = New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(MyCommand)
                Try
                    MyBuilder.GetInsertCommand()
                    MyBuilder.GetDeleteCommand()
                    MyBuilder.GetUpdateCommand()
                    MyCommand.Update(dataset, query(0))
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MsgBox(query(0) & " update failed." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & ex.Message)
                End Try
                Next
    End Using
```

bidSummaryQueries is an ArrayList I populate, at this point it has these in it:

```
{"ProjectInfo", "SELECT * FROM [ProjectInfo$] WHERE [" & PROJECT & "] <> ''"}
{"ArchitectInfo", "SELECT * FROM [ArchitectInfo$] WHERE [" & ARCHITECT & "] <> ''"}
{"BidInfo", "SELECT * FROM [BidInfo$] WHERE [" & PROJECT & "] <> ''"}
{"ContractorInfo", "SELECT * FROM [ContractorInfo$] WHERE [" & CONTRACTOR & "] <> ''"}
{"ContactInfo", "SELECT * FROM [ContactInfo$] WHERE [" & CONTRACTOR & "] <> ''"}
```

Thanks for any help =)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to definie a VB.NET DataTable Column as primary key after creation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2470681/how-to-definie-a-vb-net-datatable-column-as-primary-key-after-creation)

Comment: Hey, to clarify, I already have my DataTable Column primary keys defined (which I do after creation...). That's working fine, the issue is that when I go to use CommandBuilder it complains that the selectcommand doesn't return key column information, which it wouldn't since my excel doesn't have key columns explicitly defined.
I need help satisfying CommandBuilder's key column requirement.

Comment: add the VB CODE that creates the command builder including the SQL UPDATE command and the place where the error is thrown to your question. Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391924/updating-excel-sheet-using-oledb may help

Comment: Nevermind. I found a link (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2008/10/29/how-to-update-an-excel-worksheet-using-dataset-and-the-oledbdataadapter.aspx) that says you cannot use CommandBuilder to update Excel, and you can't Delete on Excel rows at all, so now I'm just copying the information into a local SQL Database. 
Thank you for your help anyway xmojmr!

Comment: in that case you may find useful one of the open source .NET libraries for working with Excel files (in a different but less deprecated way) listed e.g. here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23881486/2626313